# How check user have tg subscribe premium when start bot use node.js and telegraf.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegraf.js

I'm trying to pull the data, whether the user has a premium tg, but it does not work.

Сan you know the solution to this problem and help me?

Answer (score -1):

The Telegram Bot Api provides you with an [`User`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user) object, representing a Telegram user.

This object contains the following field:

> `is_premium`
> Type: True
> *Optional*. True, if this user is a Telegram Premium user

This has been added in [Bot API 6.1](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api-changelog#june-20-2022), released on June 20, 2022

---

So you'll just need to use Telegraf to get the User object, and check if the `is_premium` key is set.

Example, the `User` should be available as `from` on `ctx`:

```
bot.on(message('text'), async (ctx) => {

  const is_premium = ctx.from.is_premium;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf')

const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)

bot.command('check_premium', async (ctx) => {
  const chatId = ctx.message.chat.id
  const userId = ctx.message.from.id
  
  try {
    const chatMember = await ctx.telegram.getChatMember(chatId, userId)
    const isPremium = chatMember.status === 'creator' || chatMember.status === 'administrator' || chatMember.status === 'member' && chatMember.is_member == true && chatMember.can_pin_messages == true
    
    if (isPremium) {
      ctx.reply('Congratulations! You have Telegram Premium.')
    } else {
      ctx.reply('Sorry, you do not have Telegram Premium.')
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    ctx.reply('An error occurred while checking your subscription status.')
  }
})

bot.launch()
```

Comment: Your `const isPremium` makes no sense, I think you misunderstood the question.